# GraphViz : Interactive swing ui?

Tags: java, user-interface, graphviz

Hi :  Is there a way to convert a graphviz file into a GUI (i.e. using swing) ?  I want to be able to click on nodes, and plugin popups or actionlisteners associated with each node in a graphviz interface.

Im sure there exist some java API's for dealing with graphviz data, so I may simply convert a graphviz object into a jgraphT graph, and visualize that way.... But Im keeping my hopes up that somebody has had this idea before and, maybe, there exists a graphviz-ui builder, somewhere out there.

I wouldnt mind if such a ui existed in another language (i.e. python) ...  But java would be my preference.

**A Related Question**

Certainly, there are other people thinking along these lines : [Interactive Graphviz graphs in a web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6020615/interactive-graphviz-graphs-in-a-web-application)

However, I want to use graphviz to debug a large data flow, which we have mapped visually library, wherein I want to click a node, and then read some files from the local disc based on that click .  Thus, a simple javascript gui to graphviz might not be a valid solution for me.

Comment: Perhaps a first step could be to convert a graphviz file into SVG?

Answer (score 0):

I have used [ZGRViewer](http://zvtm.sourceforge.net/zgrviewer.html), which is open source java. 
It lets you navigate the graphviz generated svg, and might be a good starting point for your project.

It's not a UI builder, or API as the details of your question ask, but it is a nice graphviz interactive ui, and you might be able to get some hooks in on the existing click command.